# Linux and wget.. specify alternate link

Tags: linux, bash, wget

Is it possible to make (via Linux command line tools ) wget download from an alternate link in case the download fails ?

**Example**:

Download file.zip from http://www.secondary.com/file.zip in case it's not found at http://www.primary.com/file.zip.

Comment: Put it in a shell script that uses the exit status of the first call to determine if it failed.

Comment: I would suggest [aria2](http://aria2.sourceforge.net/) instead, it supports multi-source downloading. So if both links are good it would download from both simultaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a shell construct like this.

```
wget http://www.primary.com/file.zip || wget http://www.secondary.com/file.zip
```

The `||` is the OR operator, and depends on the fact that it "short circuits" the evaluation if the whole statement is true.  This is a functional style, where the first statement is evaluated and if it's "true" (returns zero) then the second is not evaluated. If it's "false", the second is evaluated. The side effect of evaluating these commands is downloading the file.

Answer (score 0):

---

Try something like this

```
wget_exit=$(wget "$MYURL")
if [ $? -ne 0 ];
then
    wget "$MYALTURL"
fi
```

The exit status is captured in `$?`. You could also treat specific errors differently by looking at the exit statuses of `wget` [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Exit-Status).